Keyboard disappearing after typing 1 single letter on input field, using React Native to create a WeatherApp
Hi i am making a WeatherApp for my school project using React Native, this is my first time using React Native and i have a input field to search up the city/ country however when you try to type into the input field after you type 1 single character the keyboard disappears and i have no idea why, could someone please help me?
this is my code (i removed the API key on purpose to put it here):
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import {
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View,
      TextInput,
      TouchableOpacity,
      Alert,
      Image,
      ScrollView,
      Button,
    } from "react-native";
    import axios from "axios";
    import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
    import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
    import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
    
    const API_KEY = "";
    
    export default function App() {
      const [city, setCity] = useState("");
      const [weather, setWeather] = useState(null);
      const [main, setMain] = useState(null);
      const [earthquakeData, setEarthquakeData] = useState(null);
      const [forecastList, setForecastList] = useState(null);
    
      const fetchWeather = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await axios.get(
            `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`
          );
          setWeather(response.data);
          const mainData = response.data.main;
          setMain(mainData);
        } catch (error) {
          Alert.alert("Error", "City not found");
        }
      };
    
      const forecastWeather = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await axios.get(
            `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${city}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`
          );
          console.log(response);
          const listData = response.data;
          setForecastList(listData);
        } catch (error) {
          Alert.Alert("Cant find the forecast");
        }
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchEarthquakeData = async () => {
          try {
            const response = await axios.get(
              "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query",
              {
                params: {
                  format: "geojson",
                  limit: 5,
                  orderby: "time",
                },
              }
            );
            setEarthquakeData(response.data);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching earthquake data:", error);
          }
        };
    
        fetchEarthquakeData();
      }, []);
    
      const iconMapping = {
        "01d": require("./media/01d.png"),
        "01n": require("./media/01n.png"),
        "02d": require("./media/02d.png"),
        "02n": require("./media/02n.png"),
        "03d": require("./media/03d.png"),
        "03n": require("./media/03n.png"),
        "04d": require("./media/04d.png"),
        "04n": require("./media/04n.png"),
        "09d": require("./media/09d.png"),
        "09n": require("./media/09n.png"),
        "10d": require("./media/10d.png"),
        "10n": require("./media/10n.png"),
        "11d": require("./media/11d.png"),
        "11n": require("./media/11n.png"),
        "13d": require("./media/13d.png"),
        "13n": require("./media/13n.png"),
        "50d": require("./media/50d.png"),
        "50n": require("./media/50n.png"),
      };
    
      function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <LinearGradient
              colors={["#1C2547", "#503F9D", "#8250AC"]}
              style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <View
                style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
                <Image
                  style={styles.homeImage}
                  source={require("./media/home-image2.png")}></Image>
                <Text style={styles.bigText1}>EarthSky</Text>
                <Text style={styles.bigText2}>Weather</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.homeButton}
                  onPress={() => navigation.navigate("test")}>
                  <Text style={styles.homeButtonText}>Get Weather</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </LinearGradient>
          </View>
        );
      }
      function WeatherDetails() {
        return (
          <ScrollView style={styles.ScrollView}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <LinearGradient
                colors={["#5735b2", "#4d32a4", "#4b31a2", "#462f9a"]}
                locations={[0.07, 0.37, 0.61, 0.84]}
                style={styles.linearGradient}>
                <View style={styles.bigContainer}>
                  <Text style={styles.title}>Weather App</Text>
                  <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder="Search for a place"
                    placeholderTextColor="#EBEBF5"
                    value={city}
                    onChangeText={setCity}
                  />
    
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.button}
                    onPress={() => {
                      fetchWeather();
                      forecastWeather();
                    }}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Get Weather</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  {weather && main && (
                    <View style={styles.weatherContainer}>
                      <View style={styles.left}>
                        <Text style={styles.weatherTempText}>
                          {parseFloat(weather.main.temp).toFixed(0)}°
                        </Text>
                        <View>
                          <Text style={styles.weatherMaxLowText}>
                            H: {main.temp_max}° L: {main.temp_min}°
                          </Text>
                          <Text style={styles.weatherText}>
                            {weather.name}, {weather.sys.country}{" "}
                          </Text>
                        </View>
                      </View>
                      <View style={styles.right}>
                        <Image
                          source={iconMapping[weather.weather[0].icon]}
                          style={styles.image}
                        />
                        <Text style={styles.weatherText}>
                          {weather.weather[0].main}
                        </Text>
                      </View>
                    </View>
                  )}
                  <View>
                    {forecastList && forecastList.list && (
                      <>
                  <Text style={styles.title}>7-Day Forecast</Text>
    
                      <ScrollView horizontal>
                        {forecastList.list.map((forecast, index) => (
                          <LinearGradient
                          key={index}
                            colors={["#1C2547", "#503F9D", "#8250AC"]}
                            style={ styles.forecastContainer }>
                              <Text style={styles.forecastText}>
                                {parseFloat(forecast.main.temp).toFixed(0)}°
                              </Text>
    
                              <Image
                                source={iconMapping[forecast.weather[0].icon]}
                                style={styles.forecastImage}
                              />
                              <Text style={styles.forecastTempText}>
                                {forecast.dt_txt.split(" ")[0]}
                              </Text>
                          </LinearGradient>
                        ))}
                      </ScrollView>
                      </>
                    )}
                  </View>
                  <View>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>Top 5 Most Recent Earthquakes</Text>
                    {earthquakeData ? (
                      earthquakeData.features.map((earthquake, index) => (
                        <View key={index} style={styles.earthquakeContainer}>
                          <View style={styles.left2}>
                            <Text style={styles.magnitude}>
                              {parseFloat(earthquake.properties.mag).toFixed(1)}
                            </Text>
                          </View>
                          <View style={styles.right2}>
                            <Text style={styles.name}>
                              {earthquake.properties.place}
                            </Text>
                            <Text style={styles.location}>
                              {earthquake.geometry.coordinates[1]},{" "}
                              {earthquake.geometry.coordinates[0]}
                            </Text>
                            <Text style={styles.depth}>
                              {earthquake.geometry.coordinates[2]} km
                            </Text>
                          </View>
                        </View>
                      ))
                    ) : (
                      <Text>Loading...</Text>
                    )}
                  </View>
                </View>
              </LinearGradient>
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
        );
      }
    
      function DetailsScreen() {
        return (
          <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
            <Text>Details Screen</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
      const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
    
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Weather App">
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Go Back"
              component={HomeScreen}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="test"
              component={WeatherDetails}
              options={{
                headerTintColor: "#fff",
                headerTitle: " ",
                headerTransparent: true,
                hideWhenScrolling: false,
                headerBlurEffect: "regular",
              }}
            />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    }



This is the input field that i am talking about:
<TextInput
  style={styles.input}
  placeholder="Search for a place"
  placeholderTextColor="#EBEBF5"
  value={city}
  onChangeText={setCity}
/>


I think the issue you are having is redraws are causing your textInput to loose focus which is causing the keyboard to close. This should fix your issue:
    import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
    import {
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View,
      TextInput,
      TouchableOpacity,
      Alert,
      Image,
      ScrollView,
      Button,
    } from "react-native";
    import axios from "axios";
    import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
    import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
    import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
    
    const API_KEY = "";
    
    export default function App() {
      const city = useRef("");
      const [weather, setWeather] = useState(null);
      const [main, setMain] = useState(null);
      const [earthquakeData, setEarthquakeData] = useState(null);
      const [forecastList, setForecastList] = useState(null);
    
      const fetchWeather = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await axios.get(
            `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city.current}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`
          );
          setWeather(response.data);
          const mainData = response.data.main;
          setMain(mainData);
        } catch (error) {
          Alert.alert("Error", "City not found");
        }
      };
    
      const forecastWeather = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await axios.get(
            `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${city.current}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`
          );
          console.log(response);
          const listData = response.data;
          setForecastList(listData);
        } catch (error) {
          Alert.Alert("Cant find the forecast");
        }
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchEarthquakeData = async () => {
          try {
            const response = await axios.get(
              "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query",
              {
                params: {
                  format: "geojson",
                  limit: 5,
                  orderby: "time",
                },
              }
            );
            setEarthquakeData(response.data);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching earthquake data:", error);
          }
        };
    
        fetchEarthquakeData();
      }, []);
    
      const iconMapping = {
        "01d": require("./media/01d.png"),
        "01n": require("./media/01n.png"),
        "02d": require("./media/02d.png"),
        "02n": require("./media/02n.png"),
        "03d": require("./media/03d.png"),
        "03n": require("./media/03n.png"),
        "04d": require("./media/04d.png"),
        "04n": require("./media/04n.png"),
        "09d": require("./media/09d.png"),
        "09n": require("./media/09n.png"),
        "10d": require("./media/10d.png"),
        "10n": require("./media/10n.png"),
        "11d": require("./media/11d.png"),
        "11n": require("./media/11n.png"),
        "13d": require("./media/13d.png"),
        "13n": require("./media/13n.png"),
        "50d": require("./media/50d.png"),
        "50n": require("./media/50n.png"),
      };
    
      function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <LinearGradient
              colors={["#1C2547", "#503F9D", "#8250AC"]}
              style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <View
                style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
                <Image
                  style={styles.homeImage}
                  source={require("./media/home-image2.png")}></Image>
                <Text style={styles.bigText1}>EarthSky</Text>
                <Text style={styles.bigText2}>Weather</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.homeButton}
                  onPress={() => navigation.navigate("test")}>
                  <Text style={styles.homeButtonText}>Get Weather</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </LinearGradient>
          </View>
        );
      }
      function WeatherDetails() {
        return (
          <ScrollView style={styles.ScrollView}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <LinearGradient
                colors={["#5735b2", "#4d32a4", "#4b31a2", "#462f9a"]}
                locations={[0.07, 0.37, 0.61, 0.84]}
                style={styles.linearGradient}>
                <View style={styles.bigContainer}>
                  <Text style={styles.title}>Weather App</Text>
                  <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder="Search for a place"
                    placeholderTextColor="#EBEBF5"
                    defaultValue={city.current}
                    onChangeText={(text) => city.current = text}
                  />
    
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.button}
                    onPress={() => {
                      fetchWeather();
                      forecastWeather();
                    }}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Get Weather</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  {weather && main && (
                    <View style={styles.weatherContainer}>
                      <View style={styles.left}>
                        <Text style={styles.weatherTempText}>
                          {parseFloat(weather.main.temp).toFixed(0)}°
                        </Text>
                        <View>
                          <Text style={styles.weatherMaxLowText}>
                            H: {main.temp_max}° L: {main.temp_min}°
                          </Text>
                          <Text style={styles.weatherText}>
                            {weather.name}, {weather.sys.country}{" "}
                          </Text>
                        </View>
                      </View>
                      <View style={styles.right}>
                        <Image
                          source={iconMapping[weather.weather[0].icon]}
                          style={styles.image}
                        />
                        <Text style={styles.weatherText}>
                          {weather.weather[0].main}
                        </Text>
                      </View>
                    </View>
                  )}
                  <View>
                    {forecastList && forecastList.list && (
                      <>
                  <Text style={styles.title}>7-Day Forecast</Text>
    
                      <ScrollView horizontal>
                        {forecastList.list.map((forecast, index) => (
                          <LinearGradient
                          key={index}
                            colors={["#1C2547", "#503F9D", "#8250AC"]}
                            style={ styles.forecastContainer }>
                              <Text style={styles.forecastText}>
                                {parseFloat(forecast.main.temp).toFixed(0)}°
                              </Text>
    
                              <Image
                                source={iconMapping[forecast.weather[0].icon]}
                                style={styles.forecastImage}
                              />
                              <Text style={styles.forecastTempText}>
                                {forecast.dt_txt.split(" ")[0]}
                              </Text>
                          </LinearGradient>
                        ))}
                      </ScrollView>
                      </>
                    )}
                  </View>
                  <View>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>Top 5 Most Recent Earthquakes</Text>
                    {earthquakeData ? (
                      earthquakeData.features.map((earthquake, index) => (
                        <View key={index} style={styles.earthquakeContainer}>
                          <View style={styles.left2}>
                            <Text style={styles.magnitude}>
                              {parseFloat(earthquake.properties.mag).toFixed(1)}
                            </Text>
                          </View>
                          <View style={styles.right2}>
                            <Text style={styles.name}>
                              {earthquake.properties.place}
                            </Text>
                            <Text style={styles.location}>
                              {earthquake.geometry.coordinates[1]},{" "}
                              {earthquake.geometry.coordinates[0]}
                            </Text>
                            <Text style={styles.depth}>
                              {earthquake.geometry.coordinates[2]} km
                            </Text>
                          </View>
                        </View>
                      ))
                    ) : (
                      <Text>Loading...</Text>
                    )}
                  </View>
                </View>
              </LinearGradient>
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
        );
      }
    
      function DetailsScreen() {
        return (
          <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
            <Text>Details Screen</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
      const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
    
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Weather App">
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Go Back"
              component={HomeScreen}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="test"
              component={WeatherDetails}
              options={{
                headerTintColor: "#fff",
                headerTitle: " ",
                headerTransparent: true,
                hideWhenScrolling: false,
                headerBlurEffect: "regular",
              }}
            />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    }

What I did was change the city state constant to a useRef() instead. A useRef().current change keeps values through renders but doesn't itself trigger a new render.
This works because the textInput has its own internal state so it will keep track of changes for you and update the UI so you don't need the whole view re-rendering on every input change.
Disclaimer I didn't actually test this code but I am pretty confident this is your issue.
